# index 5688 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3706

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, recommendation-engine

I'm training to create recommender systems. I take the data from the site http://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
header = ['user_id', 'item_id', 'rating', 'timestamp']
df = pd.read_csv('ml-1m/ratings.dat', sep='::', names=header)
n_users = df.user_id.unique().shape[0]
n_items = df.item_id.unique().shape[0]
print ('Number of users = ' + str(n_users) + ' | Number of movies = ' + str(n_items))
```

Number of users = 6040 | Number of movies = 3706

```
from sklearn import cross_validation as cv
train_data, test_data = cv.train_test_split(df, test_size=0.25)
```

And i try to create two user-item matrices, one for training and another for testing

```
train_data_matrix = np.zeros(( n_users, n_items))
for line in train_data.itertuples():
    train_data_matrix[line[1]-1, line[2]-1] = line[3]  

test_data_matrix = np.zeros((n_users, n_items))
for line in test_data.itertuples():
    test_data_matrix[line[1]-1, line[2]-1] = line[3]
```

And i get (full traceback)

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-180dea01cdf8> in <module>()
      2 train_data_matrix = np.zeros(( n_users, n_items))
      3 for line in train_data.itertuples():
----> 4     train_data_matrix[line[1]-1, line[2]-1] = line[3]
      5 
      6 test_data_matrix = np.zeros((n_users, n_items))

IndexError: index 5688 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3706
```

what's wrong?

P.S.

```
train_data.head()
      user_id  item_id rating      timestamp
483019  2968    2268    5       971107926
943582  5689    3615    3       963719230
116153  752     1147    5       975458000
103250  686     1704    5       975601762
235333  1425    3752    4       1023560349
```

P.S.S

```
for line in train_data.itertuples():
    print (line)
Pandas(Index=483019, user_id=2968, item_id=2268, rating=5, timestamp=971107926)
Pandas(Index=943582, user_id=5689, item_id=3615, rating=3, timestamp=963719230)
Pandas(Index=116153, user_id=752, item_id=1147, rating=5, timestamp=975458000)
Pandas(Index=103250, user_id=686, item_id=1704, rating=5, timestamp=975601762)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling us that `train_data_matrix` has shape (3706,n), while `line[1]-1` is 5688.

```
IndexError: index 5688 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3706
train_data_matrix[line[1]-1, line[2]-1] = line[3]
```

So the question is - why is is `line[1]` equal to 5689?  Or in the larger context, why does `train_data.itertuples()` produce lines with values this large?

I wonder if you should instead be using

```
train_data_matrix[line[0]-1, line[1]-1]
```

I'm not familiar with `itertuples`. What are the elements of `line`?  What is the full shape of `train_data`?

Comment: train_data_matrix - matrix of unique values user's & movie's id. 5689 - this is user's id
train_data.head()

Comment: I answered in my question

Comment: But rows of a matrix are indexed by row count, not user id.

Comment: I've done train_data.reset_index(drop=True) but it does nor work

Answer (score 0):

You can use train_data.pivot instead.

```
train_data_matrix = train_data.pivot(index='user_id', columns='item_id', values='rating').fillna(0)
```